# Closure of a set under a function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathit{f:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}}$ be defined by the formula $\mathit{f(x,y)\,\mathtt{=}\,xy}$. Let $\mathit{P}$ be the set of all prime numbers. What is the closure of $\mathit{P}$ under $\mathit{f}$?

My attempt of a solution is first to define a union of set such that:

$$\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{Z^+}}P_n$$ 
where $P_1=P$ and for every $n\ge1$,$$P_{n+1}=  \{f(x,y)\mid x\in P_n\ \mathtt{and}\ y\in P_n\}$$
But after building the set, I found that $2\in P_1$ and $4\in P_2$, but 8 is not include in the set $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{Z^+}}P_n$. Thus my construction breaks down.
Generally, I need some guide for constructing closure of a set $B$ where $B\subseteq A$ under the function $\mathit{f:A\times A\rightarrow A}$. I do know how to build a closure of a set $B$ where $B\subseteq A$ under the function $\mathit{f:A\rightarrow A}$. But when the domain involves cartesian product, I am totally lost. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try $x\in P_i, y\in P_j$ for $i,j$ varying from $1$ to $n$ in the definition of $P_{n+1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the correction to define
$$
P_{n+1} = \{\, f(x,y) \ |\ x,y \in P_n\ \} \cup P_n
$$
you will indeed find that $\mathcal P =\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} P_n$ is the closure of $P$ under $f$.

The question remains, what is $\mathcal P$?

Since every $n\in\mathbb N_{>1}$ has a prime factorization $n=p_1 p_2 \cdots p_k$ where all $p_i$ are prime, i.e. $p_i\in P$, you certainly have $\mathbb N_{>1} \subseteq \mathcal P$. On the other hand, $\mathbb N_{>1}$ is closed under $f$ and contains $P$, thus $\mathcal P \subseteq \mathbb N_{>1}$. Together we have
$$
\mathcal P = \mathbb N_{>1}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

As you've noticed, you can't just take combinations from the same level here. You could do the following:

$$P_{n+1} := \{f(x,y) \mid \exists i, j \leq n \ . \ x \in P_i \wedge y \in P_j\}$$

Answer (score 1):

Try it with:$$P_{n+1}=\{f(x,y)\mid x,y\in P_1\cup\cdots \cup P_n\}$$
Another possibility is:$$P_{n+1}=P_n\cup\{f(x,y)\mid x,y\in P_n\}$$ Then $P=P_1\subset P_2\subset\cdots$